# Present int as enum not without creating enum type swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, domain-driven-design

I need to show int param as enum in swagger documentation

I'm using ddd and asp.net core 2.2. All my enums are stored in domain project. I don't want to dublicate them on PL or create reference to it. I need to show my int as emuns in swagger documentation

Currently int is not providing any options in swagger documentation but I want them to show some

Comment: Not really related to DDD. Swagger/WebAPI are infrastructure hence outside of the domain layers

Comment: @Tseng, let it be so, but still, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to show your integers as enums in swagger, you could follow the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/). You also have the option to create reusable Enums. In the documentation page you will see only string examples, but it works for other type too.

Try to add an example, or a piece of code, if this solution is not working for you.

Goodbye!!